# creating two kinds of dependent variable using cplex and java

Tags: java, optimization, linear-programming, cplex

I am new to work by CPLEX. My simplified optimization problem is:

```
 objective function: 
            Maximize z1 + z2 + z3
 Subject to:   
            c1: x1 - 3 x2 + x3 <= 30
            c2: x1 + x2 + x3 >= z1
            ...
 Bounds
            x1=[0,1]
            x2=[0,1] 
            ...
```

To model this problem, my code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex();            
        IloNumVar[] z = cplex.numVarArray(3, 0.0, 1.0);
        IloLinearNumExpr objectiveExpr = cplex.linearNumExpr();

        IloLinearNumExpr constraintExpr1 = cplex.linearNumExpr();
        IloLinearNumExpr constraintExpr3 = cplex.linearNumExpr();
        IloNumVar[] x = cplex.numVarArray(3, 0.0, 1.0);
        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++){
            objectiveExpr.addTerm(1, z[i]);
        }
        IloObjective obj = cplex.maximize(objectiveExpr);
        cplex.add(obj); 
        constraintExpr1.addTerm(1, x[1]);
        constraintExpr1.addTerm(-3, x[2]);
        constraintExpr1.addTerm(1, x[3]);
        cplex.addLe(constraintExpr1, 30);

        constraintExpr2.addTerm(-1, x[1]);
        constraintExpr2.addTerm(1, x[2]);
        constraintExpr2.addTerm(1, x[3]);
        cplex.addGe(constraintExpr2, z[1]);
        .
        .
        .
    }
    catch (IloException e){
        System.err.println("Concert exception '" + e + "' caught");
    }


}
```

The generated model of this code is:

```
objective function:  
           Maximize x1 + 2 x2 + 3 x3
Subject To:               
           c1: x7 - 3 x8 + x9 <= 30
           c2: - x1 - x7 + x8 + x9 <= 0
Bounds
           0 <= x1 <= 1
           ...
```

If it starts to model the constraints from x4 instead of x7, I could distinguish x and z easily.

Comment: I don't know anything about CPLEX, but I think that for someone to help you you're going to have to say what the problem was. Did you get some error message? What was the error message? Did it not produce the expected results? What results did it produce, and what did you expect?

Comment: Thanks. My problem is complicated, so I just wrote a simplified part of it. I did not get any error,  however the code cannot model my problem correctly

Answer (score 0):

Unlike David, I *do* know CPLEX for about 17 years, but I also don't understand what your problem is. Can you explain in what way the generated model is different from what you expected - we can probably work this out ourselves, but it seems daft for potentially many of us to have to spend extra time understanding your problem when you could explain better.

Can I suggest that you name your variables and constraints using setName(...) so that you can see better what is happening in the generated model.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My problem is solved by using setname(). Thanks